# Django: how to create a record that contains one or more items from a different db tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to make a simple ticket system. I have 3 tables : **Ticket, Responsible and  Services** .I also have the views that create, update and delete data to all 3 tables. what I am having problems is creating a view that creates the main ticket.

My 3 tables are  Ticket, Services and Responsible. my ticket can only have one responsible person and  my ticket need to have one or more services.

I'm  lost on how to select multiple services to a ticket  my models looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Servicios(models.Model):
    servicio = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    precio = models.FloatField()


class Doctor(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    porcentaje = models.FloatField()

class Ticket(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    servicio = models.ForeignKey(Servicios)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    p_unitario = models.FloatField()
    total = models.FloatField()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Main:get-list')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the correct way:

```
class Servicios(models.Model):
    servicio = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    precio = models.FloatField()
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    porcentaje = models.FloatField()

class Ticket(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    p_unitario = models.FloatField()
    total = models.FloatField()
```

Here, a services can have one ticket and a ticket can have multiple services, another option would be manytomany.

Answer (score 0):

Use manytomany relation for Servicios and ForeignKey or onetoone for  Doctor
in Ticket.
By using manytomany you may be able to refer as many Servicios values as needed.